# With in a For loop only Only One Item is being appended to the div

Tags: jquery

I have been provided with this css in which i need to integarte my code .

```
<div class="orders-details-wrap">
                <h4>Order Summary</h4>
                <div class="orders-row">
                    <aside class="left-order">
                    <i>Vendor 1 <span>2 items</span></i>
                    </aside>
                    <aside class="right-order">
                    <i>Rs: <span>245.00</span></i>
                    </aside>
                </div>

                <div class="order-listdetails-wrap">
                    <div class="orderTitle">Popcorn - 250g</div>
                    <div class="orderCont">
                        <div class="img"><img src="images/img_popcorn.jpg"/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="order-listdetails-wrap">
                    <div class="orderTitle">Triple Chocolate Ice Cream</div>
                    <div class="orderCont">
                        <div class="img"><img src="images/TripleChoc.jpg"/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <section class="cartTable">
                    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="totalWrap" align="right">
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Services Charges</td>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Rs. 25.00</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr style="border:none;">
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" class="total">Total</td>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" class="total">Rs. 270.00</td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br><br><br>
                </section>

                <div class="btns-wrap">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Confirm Order</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-mrn">Edit Order</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

To integarte this with the dynamic values , i followed this way

I have this code in my HTML :

```
 <div class="orders-details-wrap" style="display:none">
 </div>
```

On click of the Confirm Order Button , i am creating this JSON .

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-confirmorder", function () {

var divdata = {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Plain salted",
            "image": "http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/popcorn.jpg",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "50"
        },
        {
            "name": "Regular Cone, Single Scoop, Vanila ",
            "image": "http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "75"
        }
    ]
};

var html = $('<h4>Order Summary</h4>');
  html.append('<div class="orders-row">
  <aside class="left-order">
  <i>Vendor 1 <span>'+divdata.data.length+' items</span>
  </i></aside><aside class="right-order">
  <i>Rs: <span>245.00</span></i>
  </aside>
  </div>');

for (var i = 1; i < divdata.data.length; i++) {
 var itemname = divdata.data[i].name;
var image = divdata.data[i].image;
 var itemhtml = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap">
                    <div class="orderTitle">Popcorn - 250g</div>
                    <div class="orderCont">
                   <div class="img"><img src="images/img_popcorn.jpg"/></div>
                   </div>
                   </div>'
} // for loop ends here 

html.append(itemhtml);

var content = '  <section class="cartTable">
                    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="totalWrap" align="right">
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Services Charges</td>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Rs. 25.00</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr style="border:none;">
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" class="total">Total</td>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" class="total">Rs. 270.00</td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br><br><br>
                </section>

                <div class="btns-wrap">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Confirm Order</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-mrn">Edit Order</a>
                </div>';

html.append(content);

$('.orders-details-wrap').append(html);
$('.orders-details-wrap').show();

});
```

When i ran this code only one item is being added to the div and also please let me know if anything needs to changed inside my code

Comment: Could anybody please help as tomorrow i need to submit this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are doing your append outside your loop, so it'll only append once. If you put your append inside your loop, it will append your html as many as your loop length. Try this :

```
for (var i = 1; i < divdata.data.length; i++) {
     var itemname = divdata.data[i].name;
     var image = divdata.data[i].image;
     var itemhtml = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap">
                       <div class="orderTitle">Popcorn - 250g</div>
                       <div class="orderCont">
                       <div class="img"><img src="images/img_popcorn.jpg"/></div>
                       </div>
                       </div>'
     html.append(itemhtml);
    } // for loop ends here
```

Comment: I am really surprised that this worked as variables `itemname` and `image` inside the loop do not get used.

Answer (score 0):

The value of **`itemhtml` is overwritten by each iteration of the loop AND THE ONE ITEM IS HARD-CODED**. You create variables `itemname` and `image` in the loop but **YOU NEVER USE THEM.** Change the for loop from:

```
for (var i = 1; i < divdata.data.length; i++) {
    var itemname = divdata.data[i].name;
    var image = divdata.data[i].image;
    var itemhtml = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap">
    <div class="orderTitle">Popcorn - 250g</div>
    <div class="orderCont">
        <div class="img"><img src="images/img_popcorn.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
        </div>'
} // for loop ends here 

html.append(itemhtml);
```

TO:

```
var itemhtml = '';
for (var i = 1; i < divdata.data.length; i++) {
    var itemname = divdata.data[i].name;
    var image = divdata.data[i].image;
    itemhtml += '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap">
    <div class="orderTitle">' + itemname + '</div>
    <div class="orderCont">
        <div class="img"><img src="' + image + '"/></div>
        </div>
        </div>'
} // for loop ends here 

html.append(itemhtml);
```

Comment: append statement should be inside loop

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, when you're appending to the DOM doing it in the loop would be very expensive. You want to manipulate the DOM as few times as possible; searching takes time and takes a toll the performance of your application.

Comment: sorry i did'nt saw that you are concatinating instead of assigning my bad

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are appending after the loop exits so it will just append the last item of the loop,it will also throw runtime error as `itemhtml` will not be available outside the loop append statement should be inside for loop so it appends every item :

```
  for (var i = 1; i < divdata.data.length; i++) {
     var itemname = divdata.data[i].name;
    var image = divdata.data[i].image;
     var itemhtml = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap">
                        <div class="orderTitle">Popcorn - 250g</div>
                        <div class="orderCont">
                       <div class="img"><img src="images/img_popcorn.jpg"/></div>
                       </div>
                       </div>';
    html.append(itemhtml);
    } // for loop ends here
```